# Open jmeter.bat from everything and report an error

Tags: jmeter

Open jmeter.bat from everything and report an error:not able to find java executable or version. please check your java installation
errorlevel=2

I started jmeter.bat from JMeter's bin directory and it started successfully. But I expect to be able to successfully launch jmeter.bat from the voidtools's Everything file search tool

Answer (score 1):

Given you have "bin" directory of your [JDK](https://openjdk.org/) in your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) environment variable you should be able to run JMeter from any 3rd-party launcher tool or shell.

[image]

You might need to restart your session after changing the PATH variable value.

If you cannot amend environment variables (i.e. you don't have enough permissions) you can add the line like:

```
set PATH=c:\java\bin;%PATH%
```

directly to jmeter.bat startup script.

More information: [JMeter Installation: How to Get Started](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation)

Comment: Very grateful for your help! But don't know why, now when I start jmeter.bat from everything tool it works successfully.

Comment: My assumption is that the computer may need to be restarted